# pyshark "TypeError: sequence item 6: expected str instance, _io.TextIOWrapper found"

Tags: pyshark

I am using pyshark for live packet capture. when I pass a parameter output_file  = myFilObject for saving captures to a file,
getting following error on sniffing line. If output_file parameter is removed, this works absolutely fine. Please suggest.

MySampleCode:

```
import pyshark

def capturePacket():
  outputF = open('capturepcap.pcap', 'w')
  cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='Ethernet 8', output_file=outputF)
  cap.sniff(timeout=60)
  outputF.close()
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\wxyz\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.6.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>    
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\wxyz\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.6.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\wxyz\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.6.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 269, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\wxyz\Documents\automation\practice_set_script\paket_capture\basic_packetCapture.py", line 29, in <module>
    capturePacket()
  File "c:\Users\wxyz\Documents\automation\practice_set_script\paket_capture\basic_packetCapture.py", line 22, in capturePacket
    cap.sniff(timeout=60)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 137, in load_packets  
    self.apply_on_packets(keep_packet, timeout=timeout, packet_count=packet_count)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 274, in apply_on_packets
    return self.eventloop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 283, in packets_from_tshark
    tshark_process = await self._get_tshark_process(packet_count=packet_count)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\live_capture.py", line 94, in _get_tshark_process
    tshark = await super(LiveCapture, self)._get_tshark_process(packet_count=packet_count, stdin=read)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 399, in _get_tshark_process
    self._log.debug("Creating TShark subprocess with parameters: " + " ".join(parameters))
TypeError: sequence item 6: expected str instance, _io.TextIOWrapper found
Error on reading from the event loop self pipe
loop: <ProactorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 779, in _loop_self_reading
    f = self._proactor.recv(self._ssock, 4096)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 450, in recv
    self._register_with_iocp(conn)
  File "C:\Users\wxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 723, in _register_with_iocp
    _overlapped.CreateIoCompletionPort(obj.fileno(), self._iocp, 0, 0)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
PS C:\Users\wxyz\Documents\automation\practice_set_script\paket_capture>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is these lines:

```
outputF = open('capturepcap.pcap', 'w')
cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='Ethernet 8', output_file=outputF)
```

The `output_file` [parameter](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/blob/a6a5debc30bbaa8ba1f37071ffb21fb93870cc96/src/pyshark/capture/file_capture.py) is a string and not a `io.TextIOWrapper`

> :param output_file: A string of a file to write every read packet into (useful when filtering).

So this works:

```
import pyshark

def capturePacket():
    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0', output_file='capturepcap.pcap')
    cap.sniff(timeout=60)

capturePacket()
```

Here is a [reference](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/pyshark_packet_analysis) that I put together on using `PyShark`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. So this means file object is not accepted as parameter and no need to open file, direct filename(string) should be passed

Comment: Yes, you only need to pass a string (filename.pcap), because pyshark handles all the IO stuff for you.